# How to load external variable into swf to play a different movie file using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm an AS3 noobie and need some help.

I want to load a movie dependant on a variable. For example i want to load from

'http://example.com/test/'+variable+'.mp4'

So i decide this time i want to play x.mp4 - how do i do this in AS3?

This is what i have so far:

```
// ActionScript 3.0
var video:Video = new Video();
addChild(video);

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.client = {onMetaData:ns_onMetaData, onCuePoint:ns_onCuePoint};

video.attachNetStream(ns);
ns.play("http://example.com/test/"+variable+".mp4");

function ns_onMetaData(item:Object):void {
    trace("metaData");
    // Resize video instance.
    video.width = item.width;
    video.height = item.height;
    // Center video instance on Stage.
    video.x = (stage.stageWidth - video.width) / 2;
    video.y = (stage.stageHeight - video.height) / 2;
}
function ns_onCuePoint(item:Object):void {
    trace("cuePoint");
    trace(item.name + "\t" + item.time);
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What goes wrong? At a glance, your code looks all right. What's the value of `variable`? The only thing you should need to do is to set `var variable:String = "x";` somewhere before the `ns.play` method is called.

Comment: Sorry i didnt explain myself properly. i want to set the variable outside of the file. like you would adding a click variable. clickTag=blahblah. But how do i set this up inside the file? to accept the outside variable?

Answer (score 0):

You use FlashVars for that:

http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html

Here's the code from the example. Notice that there are two different Flashvars entries:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0"
width="550"
height="400"
align="middle"
id="main">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="main.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="one=1&two=2" />
<embed src="main.swf"
width="550"
height="400"
autostart="false"
quality="high"
bgcolor="#ffffff"
FlashVars="one=1&two=2"
name="main"
align="middle"
allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

If you use swfobject (https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) it has built in support for it.

EDIT:

A more simple example would be:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html

It contains an example for just 1 variable named "myVariable":

```
LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable;
```

The page also has a test project online.

Comment: Sorry, i don't really see in the AS where it loads it dependant on an outside variable. I'm just don't know enough AS3 to know how to import a value from an external variable